# I'm trying to get an alert message to pop up using an If/Else statement, based on the answer provided

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, alert, addeventlistener

I created a question with an answer field. Ideally, if the user types in winter, which is the correct answer, an alert message of I WILL SUCCEED should pop up. Conversely, if one types in summer, an alert message of WRONG ANSWER is to appear.

If I type winter in the answer field, I get the I WILL SUCCEED alert message. Great. However, when I type summer in the answer field, I receive the alert I WILL SUCCEED. If I hit the SUBMIT button, still, I receive I WILL SUCCEED alert message, instead of my default else alert of PLEASE PROVIDE AN ANSWER!

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change it to `const answer = document.querySelector('input.answer-box').value;`

Comment: Thanks, Unmitigated! - that fixed it!

Comment: Happy to help. I've added that as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514821/9513184) now.

Comment: Please update your question with actual code not just a picture of code.  This allows us to better assist you here.

Comment: My question was answered on February 20, 2023. One of the users provided a solution, so problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `const` declaration on a variable it won't change; so, when you assign 'winter' to answer, it will always be winter and can't change to whatever the user puts in. Instead I would use `let` or `var`, and it also appears to me that `answer` isn't connected to the user's answer, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks, printAmerigo. I forgot to mention that I tried "const", but initially, that did not work. Per James Z, i tried the following, and this fixed it: const answer = document.querySelector('input.answer-box').value; I subbed out the const answer = 'winter' with the proceeding line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `answer` to `winter` so you will always get the output  I WILL SUCCEED.

Comment: Thanks for the help! While this did not help, someone posted a missing line of code that fixed my issue. Thanks again. I subbed out const answer = 'winter' with const answer = document.querySelector('input.answer-box').value;

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` to get the `<input>` element, then read its value.

```js
const answer = document.querySelector('input.answer-box').value;
```